# How can i integrate POS Customer Display with web browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, point-of-sale

**Problem**

I'm Using a Point Of Sale app in web for my store.

I record the sales in that web application which open in Google Chrome.

Now I want to connect the Customer Display to the local machine physically and want to show the bill amount to that display from the browser.

Browser : Google Chrome
Customer Display : X-Pole

**How can I integrate display ? is there any browser extension ?**

[image]

Comment: Are you using a POS device with a serial port connection, such as a receipt printer or barcode scanner? If so, try something similar. If you are new to them, look for cases where you are using a POS device with a serial port connection with the same software configuration as your application, and try something similar.

Comment: For example, run Node.js on your local machine, prepare a script to access the customer display in it, and make a request to it from your browser. Please try it.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this @Salmanul Faris

Comment: @Kachinga Not yet.

Comment: Thanks @SalmanulFaris. I already found a solution for ReactJS (JavaScript)

Comment: @Kachinga could you please share the solution here ?